# C# textbox endline

Tags: c#, database, string, ms-access, textbox

What I'm trying to do is insert, from a text box, into a MS Access database some text (no surprises). Thing is that after submitting what I have written, when I open the Access database it all appears as one string of text. So my question: is there a way in which I can determine the end of the text box per line so that when it reaches that point it would make a new line? Or something similar so that it would introduce a new line into the database file because this issue is very annoying.

P.S.: Yes the multiline option is enabled.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are the linebreaks in the value, or there should be, just print it out char by char.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to solve a non-problem. Quite possibly you'll find that you will want to show the same text in a number of different places within your application or even different applications (if it's not true now it MIGHT be true at some point in the future), so it should the the GUI to decide where and when break a text line, not your DB

Answer (score 0):

You could either detect `Environment.NewLine` within the textbox's text, or you could use the `Lines` property to access each line individually.

Comment: I have tried to have it change to a new line every 60 characters but it either moves the old text to a new line and then starts at the beginning again or it concatenates the line in the same way, after 60 chars it goes to the beginning.